# print(instead of printf()) in c/c++ program is detected by which part of compiler

Tags: c++, c, syntax, compiler-errors, semantics

Suppose I have written a c program and I have written `print` instead of `printf`.
Now my question is which part of compiler will detect this ?

Comment: Probably the parser when it tries to tokenize your statement.

Comment: @Jonathan Why did you remove the [tag:c++] tag from that question? How makes that question sense without it?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: because the title is about a C program.  Put it back if you prefer; I won't contest the re-edit as long as you also add something about C++ to the question other than just the tag.  As it stands, there is nothing except the tag about C++, which makes the C++ tag pointless.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Because the title and question body both tell us OP is using C not C++.  So the [tag:c++] is not applicable.

Comment: @BenVoigt Hmm, well. May be [@Ricky](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37092608/1413395) is on the right path. That's a horrible question, really.

Comment: Which parts of the compiler do you recognize?  The preprocessor won't recognize that there's an issue; the main compiler may or may not do so — it depends on whether you're compiling it under C90 or C99 or C11 rules (though for this purpose, C99 and C11 are the same).  The assembler won't care if it is given code to assemble (so the compiler didn't complain).  The linker will generate an error if there isn't a `print` function — or global variable — for it to link to satisfy the reference. Within the main compiler, the semantic analyzer will object to you using an undeclared function.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Why this is horrible question sir ?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thank u sir

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming OP means which part of the compiler *internally*, such as the lexer, parser, type analyzer, name analyzer, code generator, etc.

Without knowing specifically about gcc/llvm, I would assume that it's the **Name Analyzer** (more specifically, this is a part of the "Semantic Analyzer" generally, which also does Type Analysis), as that wouldn't be able to match "print" to anything that exists name wise. This is the same thing that prevents things such as:

`x = 5;`

When `x` does not exist previously.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, assume that `print` will be represented by token in the form:

```
{ token type = Identifier, token value = 'print' }
```

This transformation from source characters in tokens is done by lexical analyzer. Lets say you have function `get_token`, it reads source file characters and returns token (in the form of above structure). We can say that source file is viewed as a sequence of such tokens.

To do higher-level job we call lower-level routines, so assume now that you have function `parse_declaration` that uses `get_token`. `parse_declaration` is responsible to recognize declaration in your program (it is done using parsing algorithm, e.g. `recursive descent`) If declaration is recognized it will save `token value` in symbol table, with type information and attributes.

Now, assume you have function `parse_expression`, it will call `get_token`, and if `token type` is `Identifier` it will perform `name lookup`. This means that it will search for `token value` in the symbol table. If search is unsuccessful it will print error message (something like `"token value : undeclared identifier"`).

Of course this concept is simplified. In practice there is rather sophisticated logic for lexical analysis, parsing, semantics (how language 'behaves', name lookup is part of language semantics), and this logic should be as independent (separate) on one another as possible.